# Japanese num pad keyboard in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am running Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine. Since the last update of the Android-related files (Android SDK and AVD) to version 4.1, I have a weird looking keyboard:

[image]

*(this is the first part of the tutorial on the Android Developer website...)*

I had a real qwerty-keyboard before, but now it is not only (partly) Japanese, but I can't seem to find how to change it to a qwerty-keyboard.

I have tried checking for updates, restarting the program and the whole PC, changing AVD keyboard settings and different virtual devices with different Android versions on them (the pic shows 2.3.3).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I always have the impression that my code is one to one with an example but I am often proven wrong :P. Could you post the code? Also have you tried running this on a device?

Comment: Also I wouldn't use 4.1 with an emulator. It just came out and for the purposes of tutorials 2.3.5 is a good bet. They have worked out a lot of the issues with that version on the emulator by now, so its a safer bet. If you need 4.x, use 4.0 for now.

Comment: Oh no, turns out I actually forgot a line (the one to start the Activity) *facepalm*

Comment: The weird keyboard layout is still there though, but i will edit the question accordingly, since that's the "only" problem now... btw, I have tried numerous (also new) AVDs with several Android versions, with no improvement.

Comment: Emulators are just like that... they are software made to process assembler commands as though they are a processor. Your best bet will be to get your hands on an actual phone so things work properly. I tried using an emulator for a while and then said screw it and I run my apps of my phone now. Much better and you get a better picture of how it will run on a device (though not all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the AVD instance and create a new one.  It certainly looks strange but it won't take long to create a new virtual device and boot it ... certainly more constructive than pulling your hair out

Comment: Though I would really hate to not be able to test my apps on various versions and sizes, creating a new (4.0) virtual device helped...

Answer (score 5):

If you click and hold (your mouse button) in the input text box, a menu should come up with `Input Method`  Click that and a `Select input method` menu should appear.  Select `Android keyboard` and you'll be back to a standard qwerty keyboard.